# Facebook Redirect url to "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/read" with no access token

Tags: vb.net, facebook-authentication

I have set a web browser control in winform and navigate to the following url-

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&display=popup&scope=publish_stream,user_status&response_type=token
```

It show the login dialog box. After enter username and password facebook redirect to following
url-

```
https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=xxxxxxxx&signed_next=1&next=https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.facebook.com%252Fconnect%252Flogin_success.html&display=popup&scope=publish_stream%252Cuser_status&response_type=token&client_id=xxxxxxxxxx&ret=login&cancel_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html?error=access_denied&error_code=200&error_description=Permissions+error&error_reason=user_denied%23_=_&display=popup
```

and display a message with two button called "okay" & "cancel"

```
xyourappxxxx would like to access your public profile, friend list and status updates.
```

if i click on "Okay" button this will redirect to following page with the msg of--

```
page---https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/read
```

> message---Success  SECURITY WARNING: Please treat the URL above as you
> would your password and do not share it with anyone.
>
> application type: Native/desktop
>
> App secret in client: no
>
> Client OAuth Login: enbl
>
> Embedded browser OAuth Login: enbl
>
> Sandbox mod: ON

Problem is after authorization facebook not redirect to my redirect_uri and not getting any access token.

I am using vb.net 2008 express

thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue. If you watch really carefully, the auth token is in the URL. It just immediately redirects to a page that hides it, the idea being that your web app should grab it first before the redirect (assuming your desktop app has an embedded web browser object). This, of course, won't work if you want that token for a console app, which is what I'm trying to figure out myself.

Answer (score 4):

I might be mis-understanding your question/issue, apologies if so..
 in your first line.. you have the redirect_uri set to just go back to facebook, whereas it's supposed to be the URI of the page on your site that you want facebook to send the user to after they authenticate and approve your app,  no?

in other words shouldnt your first line be:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=**https://WWW.YOURDOMAIN.COM/YOURPAGE.ASPX**&display=popup&scope=publish_stream,user_status&response_type=token
```

after the user clicks "okay" on the popup,  it will then redirect them to YOURPAGE.ASPX on your site, passing the access_token